# StackOverflowError in a recursive method

Tags: java, stack-overflow

The program below should sum up all even numbers from n to 0 (negative) or from 0 to n (positive).

I should not use other methods or *; *=

The problem is that the program does not stop after `zaehler(counter) == eingabe` ("eingabe means "input" in English). I hope you can tell me how to solve the problem.

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Toolbox {
    public static int eingabe(int eingabe){
        if (eingabe < 0) {
            evenSum1(eingabe, 0, 0);
        } else {
            evenSum2(eingabe, 0, 0);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public static int evenSum2(int eingabe, int summe, int zaehler) {
        if (PevenSum(eingabe, summe, zaehler) == 0) {
            System.out.print("Die Summe aller geraden Zahlen ist: " + summe);
            return 0;
        }

        zaehler = zaehler - 2;
        summe = summe - zaehler;
        evenSum2(eingabe, summe, zaehler);
        return 1;

    }

    public static int evenSum1(int eingabe, int summe, int zaehler) {
        if (NevenSum(eingabe, summe, zaehler) == 0){
            System.out.print("Die Summe aller geraden Zahlen ist: " + summe);
            return 0;
        }

        zaehler = zaehler + 2;
        summe = summe + zaehler;
        evenSum1(eingabe, summe, zaehler);
        return 1;
    }

    public static int NevenSum(int eingabe, int summe, int zaehler) {
        if (zaehler == eingabe || zaehler == eingabe + 1) {
            return 0;
        }

        return 1;
    }

    public static int PevenSum(int eingabe, int summe, int zaheler) {
        if (summe == eingabe || summe == eingabe - 1) {
            return 0;
        }

        return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String eingabe;
        eingabe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hier eine Zahl eingaben");
        int zahl = Integer.parseInt(eingabe);
        eingabe(zahl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a simpler approach with much less code than you have is to have a single `sum` function (rather than having `evenSum1` and `evenSum2`), that keeps recursing until `counter` is equal to `target` or `target - 1`. Then, for positive numbers initialize `counter` to `0` and `target` to `eingabe`. For negative numbers initialize `counter` to `eingabe` and `target` to `0`. Hope that makes sense to you!

If you prefer to keep your current approach, there were a few issues with your code. I made changes to it and added comments where things had to be fixed.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class TreeNode {
    public static int eingabe(int eingabe) {
        if (eingabe > 0) { // Needed to reverse this
            evenSum1(eingabe, 0, 0);
        } else {
            evenSum2(eingabe, 0, 0);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public static int evenSum2(int eingabe, int summe, int zaehler) {
        if (PevenSum(eingabe, summe, zaehler) == 0) {
            System.out.print("Die Summe aller geraden Zahlen ist: " + summe);
            return 0;
        }
        zaehler = zaehler - 2;
        summe = summe + zaehler; // Needed to change this to add rather than
                                    // subtract (subtracting a negative number
                                    // makes it positive)
        evenSum2(eingabe, summe, zaehler);
        return 1;

    }

    public static int evenSum1(int eingabe, int summe, int zaehler) {
        if (NevenSum(eingabe, summe, zaehler) == 0) {
            System.out.print("Die Summe aller geraden Zahlen ist: " + summe);
            return 0;
        }
        zaehler = zaehler + 2;
        summe = summe + zaehler;
        evenSum1(eingabe, summe, zaehler);
        return 1;
    }

    public static int NevenSum(int eingabe, int summe, int zaehler) {
        if (zaehler == eingabe || zaehler == (eingabe - 1)) { // Changed from
                                                                // zaehler ==
                                                                // (eingabe + 1)
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public static int PevenSum(int eingabe, int summe, int zaheler) {
        if (zaheler == eingabe || zaheler == eingabe + 1) { // Can't compare the
                                                            // sum, have to
                                                            // compare counter
                                                            // and eingabe
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String eingabe;
        eingabe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hier eine Zahl eingaben");
        int zahl = Integer.parseInt(eingabe);
        eingabe(zahl);
    }
}
```